# Unity FB.AppRequest asks user to log in again

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using FB Unity SDK v7.13.0 in my game and there's a problem with second login prompt when using AppRequests. If the user does not have FB app installed and is already logged in, it works flawlessly. But, if the user has the FB app installed and has logged in from the game, when the game tries to send AppRequest (send a game gift to friend), the app opens up a webview asking them for login details. Is there any way to make plugin to login only once?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: it seems to be a deliberate functionality of FB devs